# Sanitizing non-standard characters in a webservice for XML

Tags: .net, sql-server, xml, web-services

I have a database which contains a list of users, and I occasionally pass that user list via a webservice to a remote machine.  I had a call from one of our remote facilities to say that none of the new users were showing up.

A little research turned up the problem - the webservice serves up the user list from the database as an XML file, and one of the users has a non-standard character in her name ("María").  The target PC sees this non-standard character and chokes because the XML is "broken", and therefore NONE of the records after that point are processed.

The short-term fix was easy - María became Maria.  Suddenly all the records would process without a problem.  However the long-term solution is what concerns me.  How can I somehow force recognition of these non-standard characters?

Please note that the webservice simply takes the contents of the database table and spits them out as XML; the XML file isn't anything I'm forming manually, but is rather just how the webservice does business.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you have no control over how the web service formats (encodes) the XML then you have no choice but to send it sanitized data.  This is a post on how to remove diacritics http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are creating XML by string concatenation. You should be using an `XmlWriter` to create your XML output. It will take care of correct encoding of non-ascii characters, xml entities and many other things.

If that's not the case, then xml is built correctly and xml parsing code has problems.

Comment: The XML is generated dynamically by the webservice... I declare a dataset and point it to the table, and the webservice returns that dataset (automatically converting it to XML in the process).  The consumer declares a dataset and points it to the webservice, automatically converting the XML back into a dataset.  I don't actually deal with the XML directly; rather, .NET creates the XML and consumes it in the back-end.

Comment: exactly what exception do you receive?

Comment: An invalid character was found in text content.'.
Could not find prepared statement with handle 0.
Could not find prepared statement with handle 0.
sp_xml_removedocument: The value supplied for parameter number 1 is invalid.
The XML parse error 0xc00ce508 occurred on line number 111285, near the XML text "    <WebAccountName>Mar".
The statement has been terminated.